# how to hide specific lens from search results

Tags: lenses

I want to be able to hide some search results from Dash and only show them when I click on that particular lens.

For example, I want to hide Gwibber posts from the general search results (when the "home" icon is selected) and only show the results when I select the Gwibber lens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to the lens developer to decide that. Lenses have a search_in_global property that is set to a boolean value. It is possible that you can connect to the session DBus and set the property yourself, but I haven't tried that. If you're interested, you can use D-Feet to explore the session bus.